# How to filter or find a string in an array of strings

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to filter a collection from *Mongo Atlas* with string properties: `names` and `urls`.

I am then trying to save that filtered value, store and retrieve from Mongo, and send it back to another component.

I am getting a 500 internal server error. I have tried to target the filtered name of the array, I am only returning the full array and not the result of the filter. I have added a name property to my express server and all seems to work fine.

My goal is to use the filter `water` to display the image that matches and use that value in another component to, then again filter and access the matching image.

I am successful in returning the filtered name in the names array map function which displays `name:waterfall` `<div>name:{urlName}</div`, however I am not successful in sending the same **filtered value** to *monogo*.

Also, I tried commenting out `setName(response.data.name);`, but it returns: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined** when save button is clicked.

**Gallery.js React**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { isExpired, decodeToken } from "react-jwt";
import Input from "../../Reuseables/reusableInput/Input";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import "../css/waterfall.css";
import axios from "axios";

  const Waterfall = () => {
  const [body, setBodyInput] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitleInput] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState([]);

  const history = useHistory();

  function makeRequest(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //gets data from inputs and sends to backend
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/getinput",
      data: {
        body: body,
        title: title,
        // name: name,
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      setId(response.data.data._id);
      // setName(response.data.name);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }

  const loadImage = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/geturls");
      console.log(res.data)
      setUrl(res.data.map(d=>d.url)); // array of urls
      setName(res.data.map(n=>n.name)); //array of names
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("use effect working!");
    // function checks login
    }
    loadImage();
  },[history]);

  return (
    <div className="waterfall">
      <Container className="mt-5 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <h1 className="text-center"> Post to
          <span className="text-success"> ShareVerse</span>
        </h1>
        <Form className="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicVerse">
          <Form.Label> 
              <h5>Verse Title</h5>
            </Form.Label>
            <Input setInputValue={setTitleInput} 
                   inputValue={title} 
                   inputName={'title'}
                   inputType={"text"}
          />          
            </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicVerse">
            <Form.Label>
              <h5>Verse Body:</h5>
            </Form.Label>
            <Input setInputValue={setBodyInput}  
                   inputValue={body} 
                   inputName={'body'}
                   inputType={"text"}
          />      
          </Form.Group>
          <div className="">
            <Card className="bg-dark text-white">
            {name.filter(name => name.includes('water')).map((urlName) => (
            <div>name:{urlName}</div>
            ))}
            
            {url.filter(name => name.includes('water')).map((urlData) => (
            <Card.Img name={url.name} src={urlData} alt="Card image" />
            ))}
              <Card.ImgOverlay> 
                <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">
                  <h1>{title}</h1>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Title className="text-center mt-5">{body}</Card.Title>
              </Card.ImgOverlay>
            </Card>
            <div>
              <Button 
                  className=" saveImageBtn mt-3" 
                  type="submit" onClick={makeRequest}
              > Save
              </Button>

              <div>
              <Button
                className=" saveImageBtn mt-3"
                href={`http://localhost:3000/getverse/${id}`}
              >
                View Post!
              </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Waterfall;
```

**GalleryController.js**

```
exports.PostGalleryInput = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    // res.send("recieved");
    await new Posts(req.body).save( async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        // if there is an error send the following response
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Something went wrong, please try again later.",
        });
      } else {
        // if success send the following response
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Post Created",
          data,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Seems the issue/error is thrown when you attempt to save a record in your MongoDB. Do you have access to see what that error is?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for responding. I have no error in my back end terminal, but i did update my question with an error I get about filter undefined, when i click save if setName(response.data.name); is not commented out

Comment: @Ajeet Shah, thank you for responding, I want to send a filtered vlaue of the names array, I have 14 names in the array and one that has the name "water" in it, I want to send that value to back end. The back end name has value of string

Comment: So `name` should be a string and not an array? This would seem to agree with the other error where you are setting `name` state to the response result... if it's now a string you can't map it. NM, you said it's undefined in the response.

Comment: @DrewReese i know for sure the title and body work, i added the name property to post to backend, the url and name is from a collection i wrote manually in atlas. in the front end i get the full name array and I am trying to get just the filtered value and i don't know the syntax.

Comment: @DrewReese the name is an array, i am just filtering the array to get the value i need to show the image that matches the value

Comment: I guess it isn't clear what the `name` filtering has to do with the backend 500 error. You are only filtering `name` array to display names, i.e. `<div>name:{urlName}</div>`. Nothing in the POST request is filtered. Please clarify what your issue is.

Comment: Well, where your "save" button is, is being rendered from a filtered `urls` array, and nothing still is updating and filtering the `names` state value that is sent with the POST request. Are you simply trying to send a single filtered name in the POST request, such as `name: name.filter(name => name.includes("water")).pop()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229612/discussion-between-julie-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think backend API is expecting a string for `name` in payload not an array of string.

So, you can do: `names.find(name => name === "water")`

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([]); // For simplicity, use plural here i.e. names

function makeRequest(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/getinput",
    data: {
      body: body,
      title: title,
      name: names.find(name => name === "water"), // Here
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    setId(response.data.data._id);
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}
```

Now, instead of hard-coding `water`, you can use a variable there (e.g. if it is stored in any state variable).

Comment: it worked, the name was waterfall not water, I was just filtering with 'water'